# Error with overflow

Tags: c++

I want to practice recursion. Here's my code

```
long int factorial(int *fact);
/*..
..*/
case '6':
        int fact;
        std::cin >> fact;
        std::cout << factorial(&fact);
        break;
/*...
...*/
long int factorial(int *fact) {
if (*fact == 0)
    return 1;
else
    return *fact * factorial(fact - 1);
}
```

And I have error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x01362789 in kalkulator.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00092FF0).
```

What's wrong?

Comment: That may heavily depend on your input from `fact`. Its very likely your stack gets quickly exhausted for bigger numbers.

Comment: Why are you passing in an `int*` instead of a plain `int`?

Comment: `fact - 1` is the memory address `sizeof(int)` bytes before `fact`, which is not what you want. You should change your prototype and function to use `int` instead of `int *`

Comment: But if I want work on original variable? I want to practice pointers to. :)

Comment: @falauthy Do ***one thing at a time***.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Can I ask why?

Comment: @falauthy If you want to alter the input variable, use a reference.  If you want to practice pointers do something that requires them, like writing your own string or vector.  Part of learning about pointers is learning when to use them and when not to.

Comment: @Miles Budnek Thanks. I have one request - can You look at my Git and make sure that I using pointers correctly? https://github.com/Fallauthy/Projects/blob/master/kalkulator/kalkulator/Source.cpp

Comment: If you want someone to review your code, you should post it over at [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  These comments aren't really an appropriate venue for such discussions.

Answer (score 0):

first of all do not pass pointer to the recursive function. but if you are insisting on working on pointers (probably as HW) modify your function as:

```
 long int factorial(int *fact) 
{
if (*fact == 0)
    return 1;
else
 {
    (*fact)--;
    return (*fact+1) * factorial(fact);
 }
}
```